# How to view our portlet in Liferay

Tags: liferay, portlet, war

I created a project in Eclipse and generated .war file of the same. I have uploaded the .war file in Liferay5.2.3 with Admin credentials using Upload File tab. Now i want to view the content of my .war file as a portlet in Liferay. What should i do..?

Answer (score 2):

Once a new portlet is created (developed) and described in the xml file, it will automatically be seen in the drop down list which you have on the top right side of the liferay(once you login to liferay with admin credentials).

Select **Add/undefined/'your portlet name'/add.**